# javac command is not able to find .class file in the current directory needed to compile a source file

Tags: javac

The files A.java and B.class(Bytecode version of B.java) are in the current directory.

A.java uses B.java in the following way:

```
class A {
 B b;
}
```

From what I have read the JDK tools first look in the directories where the Java standard libraries are installed. If the class is not found in the standard libraries, the tool searches in the class path. When no class path is defined, the default value of the class path is assumed to be the current directory. Then why is the following command not working:

```
C:\current> javac A.java
```

Comment: Have you made sure that A and B are defined in the (not recommended) default package? javac expects to find class files in a directory structure that matches package declarations.

Comment: yes, they are in the default package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package structure must match the directory structure, otherwise javac will fail.

http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html

Answer (score 2):

Comment out or get rid of the `package` statements in the begin of your classes. Since you do keep both java classes in the directory where you compile, the compiler should be able to find the B.class without trouble.